# How to update this role in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to give the roles along with the details of those roles, such as read, create, update, and delete. How to change the role data with the following criteria.

This is my expectations : [role img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLQGG.png)

This is my roles table: [roles table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51bAq.png)

This is my user_role table: [user_role table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGhg.png)

My json response after click button Edit : [json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhdPs.png)

This is my User Model :

```
public function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot([
    'rd',
    'cr',
    'up',
    'dl'
  ]);
}

public function hasAnyRoles($roles) {
 return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('kd_role', $roles)->first();
}

public function hasAnyRole($role) {
  return null !== $this->roles()->where('kd_role', $role)->first();
}

public function karyawan() {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Karyawan', 'nik', 'nik');
}

public function roleUser() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\RoleUser');
}
```

This is my User Update Controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
  $user = User::find($id);

  for($i = 0; $i < count($request->roleUser); $i++) {
        $roleUser[] = [
            'role_id'   => $request->roleUser[$i],
            'rd'        => $request->rd[$i],
            'cr'        => $request->cr[$i],
            'up'        => $request->up[$i],
            'dl'        => $request->dl[$i],
            'user_ins'  => auth()->user()->nik,
        ];
    }

    RoleUser::insert($roleUser);

    $user->roles()->sync($request->roleUser);

    // return  json_encode($roleUser);
    return redirect('/users')->with('status', 'Data Berhasil Diperbarui!');
}
```

And this is my view :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    @if ($roles->count())
    @foreach($roles as $role)
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input name="roleUser[]" value="{{$role->id}}" {{ $user->hasAnyRole($role->kd_role)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheck{{$role->id}}" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{$role->id}}">{{$role->nm_role}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{-- Testing --}}
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input value="true" name="rd" class="custom-control-input" {{ ($role['status']->rd == true)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheckR{{$role->id}}" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckR{{$role->id}}">Read</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input value="true" name="cr" class="custom-control-input" {{ ($role['status']->cr == true)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheckC{{$role->id}}" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckC{{$role->id}}">Create</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input value="true" name="up" class="custom-control-input" {{ ($role['status']->up == true)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheckU{{$role->id}}" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckU{{$role->id}}">Update</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input value="true" name="dl" class="custom-control-input" {{ ($role['status']->dl == true)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheckD{{$role->id}}" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckD{{$role->id}}">Delete</label>
                </div>
                {{-- End Testing --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `$request->roleUser` is `role ID` then your code should be:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $userRoles= [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->roleUser); $i++) {
        $userRoles[$request->roleUser[$i]] = [
            'rd'        => $request->rd[$i],
            'cr'        => $request->cr[$i],
            'up'        => $request->up[$i],
            'dl'        => $request->dl[$i],
            'user_ins'  => auth()->user()->nik,
        ];
    }

    $user->roles()->sync($userRoles);      
}
```

> Untested code. Please don't use in production without testing.

Comment: after i click the edit button, it is thrown into the root url. I don't know why it was like that, before it was the same.

Comment: but if i remove this syntax 
'rd'        => $request->rd[$i],
'cr'        => $request->cr[$i],
'up'        => $request->up[$i],
'dl'        => $request->dl[$i],
its works like before

Comment: I am unable to understand you. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I don't get an error, but after I press the edit button it will be thrown into the root url.

Comment: Before I add rd, cr, up, dl, when updating roles can work properly. but when i add rd, cr, up, dl, i have difficulty.

Comment: Are you using any **middleware** that checks for permission and redirects?

Comment: yea, i using middleware for roles, but not for permission read, create, update, and delete

Comment: Edit your question and paste your `middleware` 's code

Comment: I use middleware only in its role, but not in read, create, update, and delete